# Lookup multiple values in a different table given a cell containing multiple delimited values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I have two tables, which look like this:

[image]

I would like Excel to use the value in `ID company associated` in table 2 (green), look for it in table 1 (orange) and return the value from `Company name`, or multiple values when multiple companies are associated with the same person in table 2.

What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a formula that will work in Excel 2016, as is. In earlier versions of Excel, a poly-fill UDF for `TEXTJOIN()` is required. (See [this post](//superuser.com/a/1331555) for a basic one.)

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `F2` and copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the column:

```dart
{=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,INDEX(B:B,N(IF(1,MATCH(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(E2,";",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(E2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E2,";",""))+1))-1)*99+((ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(E2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E2,";",""))+1)))=1),99),A:A,0)))))}
```

Note that this formula only works if the values in column `A` are actually stored as numbers. For text values, the `--MID(…)` in the formula needs to be replaced by `TRIM(MID(…))`.

---

The prettified formula is as follows:

```dart
{=
  TEXTJOIN(
  ";",
  TRUE,
  INDEX(
    (B:B),
    N(IF(1,
      MATCH(
        --MID(
          SUBSTITUTE(E2,";",REPT(" ",99)),
          99*(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(E2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E2,";",""))+1))-1)
          +(1=ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(E2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E2,";",""))+1))),
          99
        ),
        (A:A),
        0
      )
    ))
  )
)}
```

**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.
- The brackets around `(A:A)` in the prettified version are required to force the `A:A` to remain on its own line. The same applies for the `(B:B)`.

---

For Excel 2016 (Windows only) the following simpler formula should work:

```dart
{=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,INDEX(B:B,N(IF(1,MATCH(--FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(E2, ";", "</b><b>") & "</b></a>", "//b"),A:A,0)))))}
```

Just like the previous formula, this one also only works on values stored as numbers. For text values, just remove the `--` from the formula.

Comment: Hi RobinCTS, thanks for the answer provided, it works tremendously. A last question related to the above: how do I have the formula to add a separator between names, say a semicolon between company name? Much appreciated.

Comment: @Lucio Umm, it already does that. That's what the first `;` in the formula is for. You can also change it to any other separator string. PS If you really appreciated my help, once you reach 15+ reputation don't forget to come back and upvote my answer as well ;-)

Comment: At a first look, it seems like I'm getting only 1 value for every cell in column F (1 company name per cell in column F). I was expecting at least a few cells with multiple values separated by a semicolon. It is possible, but very unlikely given the data set I'm working with. I will investigate thoroughly the file and get back to you. PS: Will do.

Comment: @Lucio You need to array-enter the formula using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`, instead of just `Enter`. (That's why the braces are there - to remind you to do so ;-) ) PS It isn't the cause of your issue, but for future reference I have added information to the answer concerning numbers stored as text versus numbers stored as actual numbers PPS I've also slightly simplified the non-prettified first formula. (The prettified version was already the simpler version.)

Comment: Worked 100%. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Is there a way that this formula could return a text value located in column E? If column E contains a mix of numbers and text values, could the formula return both the name associated to the number and the text value? Example: E3 contains "2;3;Johnny" -> Formula returns "B;C;Johnny". Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lucio Yes. The solution is too long to fit in a comment, though,and is not really suitable to add to this answer. You need to post a new question, linking it back to this question for context. Make sure the new question is self contained though. You can ping me when you've done that by posting a comment here.

Comment: thank you, I posted a new question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1334872/excel-textjoin-formula